# how can I extract values from one cell to make it multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, query

if i had a table like this:

```
------------------------------------------
user  | list_of_jobs                       |
------------------------------------------
1     |   [dentist] | [farmer] | [fisher]  |
------------------------------------------
2     |   [doctor]                         |
------------------------------------------
```

how can I convert that to something like this:

```
----------------------------------------------
user  | job                                  |
----------------------------------------------
1     |  dentist                              |
----------------------------------------------
1     |  farmer                               |
----------------------------------------------
1     |  fisher                               |
----------------------------------------------
2     |  docter                               |
----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

If the "list_of_jobs" is a known set of values, you can use UNPIVOT to do this, see [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017)

If it is an unknown set of values, you can use STRING_SPLIT in SQL Server 2016 or higher, see [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). NOTE: Your database compatibility level needs to be 130 or higher.

If you have SQL Server 2014 or earlier, or your compatibility level is below 130, you will need to write a user function to do the string splitting. [Here's a good example](https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/split-delimited-strings).